# Let $p$ be a prime number and $G$ a group of order $p^2$. Show that $G$ has at most $p +1$ subgroups of order $p$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number and $G$ a group of order $p^2$. Show that $G$ has at most $p +1$ subgroups of order $p$.

To be honest, sometimes I tried to read the content, and could not get out of place in this issue, so I hope you understand it seeing the resolution or some idea.

Comment: Try counting the distinct elements of the different subgroups

Comment: Let $P$ be a subgroup of order $p$. By Lagrange's theorem, the possible orders of subgroups of $P$ are ___ and _. Hence, if $Q$ is another subgroup of order $p$, we have $P \cap Q = $ \_ or $P \cap Q = $ \_. Now count how many elements each subgroup contributes.

Comment: It's well-known (as far as I recall) that there are only two possible groups (up to isomorphism) of order $p^2$, namely $C_{p^2}$ and $C_p\times C_p$. The first has $p-1$ subgroups of order $p$, the second has $p+1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is prime, then every subgroup of order $p$ is cyclic and every member of that subgroup is a generator. Therefore two distinct subgroups of order $p$ only intersect at the identity element. (There are other ways to see this too, but this is one way.) So every subgroup of order $p$ contributes $p-1$ distinct non identity elements to the group. So what would the size of the group be if you had more than $p+1$ subgroups of order $p$?